# Pass javascript data from view into coffeescript function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a view that generates a map for a specific district (available in @district). My map plotting code is coffeescript available to every page but it needs data available as a set of json files (district1.json, district2.json, etc). The first way I got this working was to load this variable in my view, making it globally available.

```
# in my view
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d_data = <%= render file: "#{Rails.root}/data/district_data/#{@district}.json" %>
</script>
```

Then I use the following coffeescript accepting this global variable:

```
$(document).ready ->
  if $("#users-district-display")
    myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(d_data.centroid.lat,d_data.centroid.lon)
```

This works well for this page, but I now throw errors on all pages that don't define d_data. Also, I made these json files available at mysite.com/district_data and was thinking of using .get to bring in the data from ajax (and let the view load quickly), but I still have to the the @district parameter in there.

I know I could just render the js as a partial, and am going to do that unless I can find a way to make this coffeescript work.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Regards,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just check to see if the data was defined?

```
$(document).ready ->
  if $("#users-district-display") and d_data
    myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(d_data.centroid.lat,d_data.centroid.lon)
```

Also, if you want to create a new `LatLng` object with zero parameters, you can always use the existential operator (?):

```
$(document).ready ->
  if $("#users-district-display")
    myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
      d_data?.centroid.lat || 0
      d_data?.centroid.lon || 0
    )
```